# Can we trust Solidity's `now`?

Tags: solidity

I am going to use a timestamp for certain quite important functionality. I am going to use `now`. Now my question is: can I trust this? Can I trust nodes not to tamper with this? How do other nodes verify that once the transaction is mined that the miner had correct time on his machine?

Comment: Miners can try to postpone transactions, so you might want to avoid relying on a time-resolution smaller than Ethereum median block time (which at present is approximately 15 seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `now` is off more than 2 minutes (or was it 3 minutes), the network rejects the block from the miner. It is accurate enough for "meeting start time" or "sale start time" like objectives.